# KTOR - Unzip file in POST routing

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to unzip a file zip sent within the body of a http query (content type: application/x-gzip) in Ktor (bloc rounting).
I've tried this:

val zip_received=call.receiveStream()
val incomingContent = GZIPInputStream(zip_received).toByteReadChannel()

But I got this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Acquiring blocking primitives on this dispatcher is not allowed. Consider using async channel or doing withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { call.receive().use { ... } } instead.

I'm not able to write such function.
Can I have some helps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to read GZip uncompressed request body as string:

```
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 9090) {
        routing {
            post("/") {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    call.receive<InputStream>().use { stream ->
                        val gzipStream = GZIPInputStream(stream)
                        val uncompressedBody = String(gzipStream.readAllBytes())
                        println(uncompressedBody)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Comment: Hi.Thank you it works perfect. I just have to change readBytes() instead of readAllBytes because this method does not exist. May be it is my version of GZIPInputStream.